# Wordpress run importer error 405 Not allowed

Tags: xml, wordpress, nginx, import, shared-hosting

I recently get a Bluehost hosting service I am trying to export all content from Wordpress.com to Wordpress.org into new host.

Exporting 151 XML files from Wordpress.com to new host on Wordpress.org is the real problem.
Since day one, When I import with Wordpress run importer, error pops out:

> 405 Not allowed nginx/1.10.2

[image]

Then I try to go back and try again the uploading, and it goes around 4 or 5 times until appears this:

> error the files does not exist, please try again.

[image]

Then I have to go to search again the file and try the import one more time, until:
all files shows like this. Named like: "already exist"

So I try everything, I even talk with people from Wordpress and they tell me the XML export file are working perfectly fine.
I tried talking first with Bluehost people service and they tell me this:

1. Uploading XML files are not the real problem (each file are from 4.9MB to 6.1MB I've got 100MB to import).
2. The problem with Bluehost is that I’m abusing in fulling /tmp folder every time I try to import this XML
3. Bluehost warned and even deactivated my account because my currently account is the abuser of filling the /tmp folder and is damaging to other servers.
4. I try to change php.ini values

   ```
   memory_limit = 300M
   post_max_size = 200M

   upload_max_filesize = 100M

   max_execution_time = 600
   ```

   also
   I’ve changed

   `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', ‘128M’)`

   does not work!
5. I have read that is about clear /tmp folder but I do not know how is going, because Bluehost does not allow me to clear the tmp folder, they have to do it for me, and then they notice I’ve abused that filling up, then comes deactivation I sincerely trying to put this together, but I panicked! because they think I’m doing other thing, I don’t know, they thrilling me like hacker or something.
6. I try to use Filezilla to submit all my XML files but it didn’t work, or at least I know all files are into /public_html, but then....?
7. I’ve read that cleaning tmp/mysql_slow_queries logs will be working, but you have to clean from FileManager or from editing the code and how?
8. I’ve tried to use plugin like WP all import, works to import the file but I have to edit 1000 times because each XML contents so much info and does not allow me to put image (I  have to pay the pro version).
9. So I only have 16 Xml left to  import, but I am afraid of having ‘abusing' fulling /tmp folders and deactivate the account. I'm losing my nerve, I'm losing money, unfortunately I can’t afford to pay people for help to import and set all this thing. I depend on this blog to survive.
10. Wordpress and Bluehost told me that XML are fine, and manageable, BH easily upload XML files into my /public_html the thing is probably is because I got internet 6.39Mbps to upload and each file is from 4.9MB to 6.1MB?

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add unit of measurement

```
memory_limit = 300M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Comment: then comes this: File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

Comment: I haven't idea! Something is wrong with your zmk maybe then! If you can write some in skype I can try to help you :)

Comment: *xml maybe then

Skype: etomoynik

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue and Bluehost has been no help :(

Answer (score 0):

Set `max_input_time` to `-1` in your `php.ini` file.

`max_input_time = -1`

More info here: http://php.net/max-input-time